# set a Value in an ArrayList for an existing entry

Tags: java

I want to create a small Parking System that four classes: one for the user inputs, one with ArrayList (CarPark) maintaining a list of Slots in the Parking, one ParkingSlot Class and one Car Class.

One of the options in the user menu is to park a car in an existing PakingSlot. To do so, the user needs to enter the registration number of the car. As next, the car should be parked in a parking lot and the ArrayList should be updated.

First the user creates the ParkingSlot as an object of the ArrayList in CarPark. The object includes the class Car in it which is "null".
An option of the user interface menu allowes the user to parkCar in the created Slot.
Here I struggle to program the system in a way that the car is assigned to the particular Slot. After it is assigned the car should apear next to the slot Id when the method listSlots from the CarPark class is called.

The Part of the Application Class that creates the spot in the arrayList:

```
if (choice == 1) {
System.out.println("Enter an ID of the type \"D##\"");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.matches("[D][0-9]{2}")) {
       if (carParkObj.hasParkingSlot(input) == false) {
        carParkObj.addParkingSlot(input, "Visitor");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Invalid Input. This slotID alreasy exists!");
       }
       break;
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
   }
   break;
}
```

The Part of the Application Class that takes the car registration:

```java
else if (choice == 4) {
    System.out.println("Enter the car registration number of the type \"A1234\" ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{4}")) {
      String newRegistrationNumber = input;
      System.out.println("Enter owner's name");
      String newOwner = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Is the owner Visitor or Staff member? For enter \"V\" for Visitor or \"S\" for staff member.");
      input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("V")) {
        boolean staffMember = false;
        Car car = new Car(newRegistrationNumber, newOwner, staffMember);
         //not sure that method do I need here to add the car to the Slot with the particular ID

        else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }

    }
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    break;
}
```

**The CarPark Class:**

```java
public class CarPark {
    private ArrayList<ParkingSlot> slots;       

    public CarPark() {
        slots = new ArrayList<ParkingSlot>();
    }
    /**
     * storing Parking Slot 
     */

    public void addParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean newOccupied) {

        ParkingSlot slotObj = new ParkingSlot(newId, newType, newOccupied);
        slots.add(slotObj);
    }

    public void deleteParkingSlot(String identifier) {
        Iterator<ParkingSlot> it = slots.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            ParkingSlot slot = it.next();
            String id = slot.getId();
            if(id.equals(identifier)) {
                if(slot.isOccupied() == true) {
                    System.out.println("Slot cannot be deleted because is occupied");
                }
                else {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void listSlots() {
    Iterator<ParkingSlot> it = slots.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }  
}
```

**The ParkingSlot Class:**

```java
public class ParkingSlot {

    private String id;
    private String type;
    private boolean staffMember = false;
    private Car car;

    public ParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean staffMember) {
       this.id = newId;
       this.type = newType;
       this.staffMember = staffMember;
       this.car =null;
    }

    // Getters and setters

    public void setOccupied(boolean staffMember) {
        this.staffMember = staffMember;
    }
    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return car != null;
    }
    public void parkCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
    public void removeCar() {
        this.car = null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return id + "\t" + type + "\t" + staffMember + "\t" + car;
    }
}
```

**The Car Class:**

```
public class Car {

    private String registrationNumber;   
    private String owner;

    public Car(String newregistrationNumber, String newOwner) {
        // Initialize instance variables
        this.registrationNumber = newregistrationNumber;
        this.owner = newOwner;
    }

    // Setters and getters

    public String toString() {
        return registrationNumber + owner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to assign a car to a specific slot would be to iterate through your ArrayList of slots until you find the slot with the ID you want, the same way you do to delete parking slots.

A neater way would be to store your parking slots as a `Map<String, ParkingSlot>`, where the key is the ID of the slot and the value is the slot itself. You can then simply access the slot through its ID.

Since the keys of a Map are a set, this would also give you a way to quickly check for duplicate IDs.